# Declaring an array of KeyValuePairs?

Tags: c#, syntax

```
KeyValuePair <string, int>[] pears1 = new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{};
KeyValuePair <string, int>[] pears2 = new KeyValuePair<string, int>()[5];
KeyValuePair <string, int>[] pears3 = new KeyValuePair<string, int>()[]{};
KeyValuePair <string, int>[] pears4 = new KeyValuePair<string, int>()[5]{};
```

pears1 and pears2 are valid. pears3 and pears4 are not. Why is that? What are the differences?

Comment: `pears2` is not valid either. if you remove the `()` then it would be.

Comment: because its not the way you need to create/instantiate pears3 and pears4

Comment: You left out this one: `KeyValuePair<string, int>[] pears1 = { };`

Comment: I get it now!!!!!! I did not see a parser error so I thought pears2 is valid. I am so dumb!!!

Comment: Whenever you are working with generics, treat the hull thing as a concrete type. In this case KeyValuePair<string, int>. If you had an int array, you would write it like this: int[numberOfElements]. The same applies to generics: KeyValuePair<string, int>[numberOfElements]

Comment: @rokkerboci so "KeyValuePair<string, int>" is just like "int". Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Aominè Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake!!!! Now I understand.

Comment: @RufusL This one looks neat!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{};` works because you are instancing a new instance of `KeyValuePair<string, int>[]`(an array of KVP) with what is between the curly bracket `{}` as items which is empty. Result: an empty array of KVP.
2. `new KeyValuePair<string, int>()[5]` doesn't works because you are instancing a new instance of `KeyValuePair<string, int>`, and then you trying to to accessing the index [5]. Of course that is not going work, since KVP doesnt implement an indexer.
3. `new KeyValuePair<string, int>()[]{}` doesn't works because you are instancing a new instance of `KeyValuePair<string, int>`, and then you tried to access the indexer without an index, so already it is not going to work let alone the `{}`.
4. `new KeyValuePair<string, int>()[5]{}` suffers the same proble as #2.

So what else works?

```
new KeyValuePair<string, int>[n] // where n is >= 0
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>(), // ... repeated n times
}
```